# Simple Reverse Polish Calculator

Tags: c++, calculator, postfix-notation

I am having trouble figuring out how to store the operator that the user inputs. I think my line 36 is what is causing my problem but not sure so what happens (I'm sure you can see from the code but I can't ;)) is I get to line 35 and put in the operation to use for the integers and hit enter nothing happens I then type in any 2 alphanumeric characters hit enter and nothing then 2 alphanumeric and enter then it spits out my answer. I *know* it's probably something so easy I am missing.

Also after I get that part working I would like to add a "do while" loop for the user to continue to use whichever operator that was choose until iValue1 !=0

Lastly, is the simplest way to prevent a user to divide by 0 using an "if" cin.fail? If so would that go with my first "if" statement?

*Edit: Line 35 = "cout << "Enter the operation you want to perform:"

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float iValue1, iValue2, iValue3;

    char chOperator1 = '/';     //Initializing operators
    char chOperator2 = '*';
    char chOperator3 = '+';
    char chOperator4 = '-';

    //Get user inputs
    cout  << "Enter the first value as an integer: ";
    cin   >> iValue1;
    cout  << "Enter the Second value as an integer: ";
    cin   >> iValue2;
    cout  << "Enter the operation you want to perform: ";
    cin   >> chOperator1 >> chOperator2 >> chOperator3 >> chOperator4;


    if( chOperator1 == '/')
    {
        iValue3 = iValue1 / iValue2;
    }
    else {
        if(chOperator2 == '*')
        iValue3 = iValue1 * iValue2;
        (chOperator3 == '+');
        iValue3 = iValue1 + iValue2;
        (chOperator4 == '-');
        iValue3 = iValue1 - iValue2;
    }

    cout  << "The result is \n " << iValue3;    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We don't have line numbers. But you need to put an `else if` in front of your conditions, and not end them with `;`

Comment: The description of how the program behaves matches your code: you ask to wait with processing until you entered 4 chars, then the program proceeds to execute one of them - or none if the first char you enter is not '/'. That's probably not what you want, but the program needs a complete re-write, and it's easier to google 'reverse polish in C++' as that's so common.

Comment: @clcto: So your saying I need to put an `else if` in front of my if and remove my 
embedded `if` and `else`?

@gnometorule: How would i then implement the program to accept and recognize the one `char` that the user enters and look at my conditions to prompt the correct operation?

Comment: Vote to close, there are too many RPN Calculator questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+rpn+calculator

Comment: I suggest you use a debugger to single-step each statement to find out where your logic fails.  You could post a question, with the line number or indication where you have issues with the logic.

Comment: Can your calculator handle the expression: 4 2 + 2 * ?  In RPN calcuators, there are cases where you only input one value and one operator.  The first operator is the result from the previous expression.

Comment: I don't understand.  The program prompts for one operation, yet the program always inputs 4 operations.

Comment: The 4 2 + 2 can be handled with the do while but as far as my program looking to add an operator to the current do while that the user is at, no it doesn't handle that. To your last part about prompts one operation yet inputting 4 is precisely where I was stuck at, trying to figure out how to re-write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use an array or a std::vector for multiple operations:

```
char operations[4];
cout >> "Enter 4 operations: ";  
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
  cin >> operation[i];
}

for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
{
  const char opr = operation[j];
  switch (j)
  {
    case '*':
      cout << (iValue1 * iValue2) << "\n";
      break;
    case '/':
      cout << (iValue1 / iValue2) << "\n";
      break;
    case '+':
      cout << (iValue1 + iValue2) << "\n";
      break;
    case '-':
      cout << (iValue1 - iValue2) << "\n";
      break;
    default:
      cout << "Invalid operation, '" << oper << "'\n";
      break;
    }
  }
```